# How can I mock.patch in web script via HTTPServer?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, httpserver

I'd like to unittest web script on HTTPServer.

But mock.patch isn't working via HTTPServer.
it seems kicking subprocess inside.

For example, my web scripts has some external web access.

web script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests


class Script:
    def main(self):
        res = requests.put('http://www.google.co.jp') # get response code 405
        print('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n')
        print(res.content)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Script().main()
```

And my test script seems it can't mock the external web access.

test script:

```
import unittest
import requests
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
from threading import Thread
from unittest import TestCase, mock


class MockTreadTest(TestCase):

    def test_default(self):
        server = HTTPServer(('', 80), CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
        server_thread = Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
        server_thread.start()

        try:
            with mock.patch('requests.put', return_value='<html>mocked response</html>') as put:
                res = requests.get('http://localhost/cgi-bin/script.py')
                self.assertRegex(str(res.content), 'mocked response') # fail
                self.assertRegex(put.call_args_list[0][0][0], 'http://www.google.co.jp')

        finally:
            server.shutdown()
            server_thread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: What are you trying to test in `MockTreadTest`? It is certainly not testing the web script as of now.

Comment: Web script actually has some dababase reading/writing. I wanna to test them totally, including HTTPServer's handling, without external web access.

Comment: In general, it might be not called called 'unittest', possibly.

Answer (score 0):

The `MockTreadTest` is presently not testing the webscript. It is right now starting a WSGI server and it looks like the try block is calling a non-existent script. I recommend reading more about testing and mocking. I think you are trying to test the `main()` function in the `Script` class. Here is a test function to help you with:

```
from unittest.mock import TestCase, patch

# replace `your_script` with the name of your script
from your_script import Script  

# import the requests object from your script. IMPORTANT, do not do import request
from your_script import requests  

class ScriptTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_main(self):
        script = Script()
        # Now patch the requests.put function call going to the server
        with patch('requests.put', return_value="<html>mocked response</html>") as mockput:
            script.main()  # now call the main function <-- this is what we are testing
            mockput.assert_called_with('http://www.google.co.jp')
```

Presently you are just printing in the response in you script. So there is no way to test the return value. Use `return` statement in the `main()` function to achieve it. Then you can do as given below in the `with` block.

```
response = script.main()
self.assertIn('mocked response', response.content)
```